# Using blend for Visual Studio questions

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a program in Visual Studio Community 2015 and I am using Blend for the UI. I am using a Windows Form application rather than a WPF application. I cannot find the Tools panel in Blend to add buttons and panels to the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blend doesn't support WinForms... it uses an XAML base, which is what WPF is based on.  They are entirely different UI models.  For winforms, you'll have to stick with the VS designer, else switch to WPF.